# Program to calculate and compare the area of two rectangles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a program for school and so far I have the code below but when I try to run it it says there was an error and that compute_Area was not defined.

```
# This program will calculate and compare the areas of
# two rectangles and display which is the greater area
def main():
    length1 = int(input('Length of rectangle one: '))
    width1 = int(input('Width of rectangle one: '))
    area1 = compute_area(length1, width1)
    length2 = int(input('Length of rectangle two: '))
    width2 = int(input('Width of rectangle two: '))
    area2 = compute_Area(length2, width2)
    comparison_Area(area1, area2)
main()

def compute_Area():
    area = length * width
    return area

def comparison_Area():
    if area1 > area2:
        print()
        print('The area of rectangle one is: ', area1)
        print('The area of rectangle two is: ', area2)
        print('Rectangle one\'s area is greater.')
    elif area1 < area2:
        print()
        print('The area of rectangle one is: ', area1)
        print('The area of rectangle two is: ', area2)
        print('Rectangle two\'s area is greater.')
    elif area1 == area2:
        print()
        print('The area of rectangle one is: ', area1)
        print('The area of rectangle two is: ', area2)
        print('Rectangle\'s areas are equal.')
```

Comment: For starters, move the `main` function to the end of the script. You're calling a function which is only declared later. `php` let you do that, but not `python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling a function called `compute_area` but you defined the function as `compute_Area()`.

Also if you're passing in `length1` and `width1` into the function, you need to declare in your function declaration that you're passing in 2 variables.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question but a hint for lazy people ;)
Often if you have to write the exact same line many times, it can be done simpler..

instead of:

```
def comparison_area():
    if area1 > area2:
        print()
        print('The area of rectangle one is: ', area1)
        print('The area of rectangle two is: ', area2)
        print('Rectangle one\'s area is greater.')
    elif area1 < area2:
        print()
        print('The area of rectangle one is: ', area1)
        print('The area of rectangle two is: ', area2)
        print('Rectangle two\'s area is greater.')
    elif area1 == area2:
        print()
        print('The area of rectangle one is: ', area1)
        print('The area of rectangle two is: ', area2)
        print('Rectangle\'s areas are equal.')
```

you could also just write:

```
def comparison_area():
    print()
    print('The area of rectangle one is: ', area1)
    print('The area of rectangle two is: ', area2)
    if area1 > area2:
        print('Rectangle one\'s area is greater.')
    elif area1 < area2:
        print('Rectangle two\'s area is greater.')
    elif area1 == area2:
        print('Rectangle\'s areas are equal.')
```

The second function is doing exactly the same.